# File System Only Refreshes Manually

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, filesystems, refresh

The file system isn't automatically refreshing.

The following will not show up/change until I right click and hit refresh manually, or go up a level and then back down.

Examples:

- right click -> new -> Text Document
- right click -> rename
- select then delete

In case it's relevant, I have a tri-boot with Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 14.04, and Kali. I use GRUB 2.02 for selecting the OS, not the Windows bootloader.

Comment: Just to check, does this also happen on the desktop ?  Does it happen after a boot, or over time? Do you have mapped stuff , or is this via nas items or network shared (non-local) locations? is it occuring in the Libraries ?  does it happen in safe modes?  does it happen when the system is set to never sleep? What is your chosen View method? Do you have any added shell or start menu like programs?

Comment: It also happens on the desktop. It's a fresh install on Windows and starts right after boot. I have a single network drive not mounted by default, but the problem occurs on the local file system, not just the network drive. I have not tried safe mode. I have git added to my shell but nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Preface I do not know, and there are multiple reasons that this has occured over many versions of the system.  When the net locations are unmounted, could it be that some linking or mapping or something stupidly continuing to look for them, as that kind of occurances has happened before, adding in programs that are set to scan (av) and other stuff along those lines. Some things do not disable well, and continue to half work, so (for me) i tend to disable back further, like drivers. There is also mention of added Context menu items, as if they can cause this, they can/have caused other issues.

Comment: Hmm okay. Ill try to kill network drive persistence and do a complete pause and temporary removal of the antivirus and see if I make any progress.